# No such vhost error when I run my docker-compose container with rabbitmq inside

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I need to create a docker-compose file so that immediately after starting the container, I have a "myqueue" queue that I can start working with immediately.

I using
docker-compose:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  rabbitmq:
    image: "rabbitmq:latest"
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: user
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: pass
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: /
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: rabbitmq-enabled-plugins
        target: /etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins
      - type: bind
        source: rabbitmq.config
        target: /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
      - type: bind
        source: rabbitmq-defs.json
        target: /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-defs.json
```

rabbitmq-enabled-plugins

```
[rabbitmq_management].
```

rabbitmq.config

```
[
  {
    rabbit,
      [
        {default_user, <<"user">>},
        {default_pass, <<"pass">>},
        {default_vhost, <<"/">>},
        { loopback_users, [] }
      ]
  },
  {
    rabbitmq_management,
      [
        { load_definitions, "/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-defs.json" }
      ]
  }
].
```

rabbitmq-defs.json

```
{
  "exchanges": [
    {
      "name": "myqueue",
      "vhost": "/",
      "type": "fanout",
      "durable": true,
      "auto_delete": false,
      "internal": false,
      "arguments": {}
    }
  ],
  "queues": [
    {
      "name": "myqueue",
      "vhost": "/",
      "durable": true,
      "auto_delete": false,
      "arguments": {}
    }
  ],
  "bindings": [
    {
      "source": "myqueue",
      "vhost": "/",
      "destination": "myqueue",
      "destination_type": "queue",
      "routing_key": "*",
      "arguments": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

When I try to start it, I get the following message:

```
BOOT FAILED
===========
Exception during startup:
exit:{error,{no_such_vhost,<<"/">>}}
    rabbit_boot_steps:-run_step/2-lc$^0/1-0-/2, line 45
    rabbit_boot_steps:run_step/2, line 48
    rabbit_boot_steps:-run_boot_steps/1-lc$^0/1-0-/1, line 19
    rabbit_boot_steps:run_boot_steps/1, line 20
    rabbit:start/2, line 958
    application_master:start_it_old/4, line 293
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,rabbit,{{error,{no_such_vhost,<<"/">>}},{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]}}})
```

How do I need to change my configuration?

1. I tried removing vhost from rabbitmq-defs.json, but as expected nothing happened.
2. I tried to solve such a problem with dockerfile, but there are problems with curl and this solutions doesn't look nice

Answer (score 0):

Try using a tag with management. For example rabbitmq:management-alpine.